# Storing JSON string in Berkeley DB using C

Tags: c, json, function, pointers, berkeley-db

Below is my code:

```
#include <json/json.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <db.h>

#define  DATABASE "access.db" 

int db_json(json_object  val);

void json_parse(json_object * jobj) {

 enum json_type type;
 json_object_object_foreach(jobj, key, val) {
 type = json_object_get_type(val);
 switch (type) {
 case json_type_string: printf("type: json_type_string, ");
 printf("value: %s\n", json_object_get_string(val));
 db_json(val);  
 break;
 }
 }
 }

 int db_json(json_object  val) {

typedef struct {

char data1[500];

} pearson_record;

pearson_record s;


int i =0;
 DB *dbp;
    DBT key, data;
    int ret, t_ret;
    int recno;



    if ((ret = db_create(&dbp, NULL, 0)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "db_create: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
        exit (1);
    }

    // if ((ret = dbp->set_flags(dbp, DB_RECNUM)) != 0) {
        // fprintf(stderr, "db_create: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
        // exit (1);
    // }

    if ((ret = dbp->open(dbp,
        NULL, DATABASE, NULL, DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0664)) != 0) {
        dbp->err(dbp, ret, "%s", DATABASE);
        goto err;
    }

    strncpy(s.data1, val, strlen(val)+1);

    //printf("chk %\n",jvalue);

    recno = 10;

    memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key));
    memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));
    //memset(&s, 0, sizeof(struct pearson_record));
    key.data = &recno;
    key.size = sizeof(recno);
    data.data = &s;
    data.size = sizeof(s);


     if ((ret = dbp->put(dbp, NULL, &key,&data,0)) == 0)
    printf("db: %d: key stored.\n", *(int *)key.data);
    else
    {
        dbp->err(dbp, ret, "DB->put");
        goto err;
    }

    pearson_record *ppr;
         if ((ret = dbp->get(dbp, NULL, &key, &data, 0)) == 0) {

    ppr = (pearson_record *) data.data;

    printf("db: %d: key retrieved: data was %s %d\n",
            *(int *)key.data, ppr->data1, data.size);
    }
    else {
        dbp->err(dbp, ret, "DB->get");
        goto err;
    }

    err:    if ((t_ret = dbp->close(dbp, 0)) != 0 && ret == 0)
        ret = t_ret; 

        exit(ret);
    }

int main() {
 char * string = "{\"Extracurricular\" : \"5,6,7,41,40,22,9,12,91,97\"}";
 printf ("JSON string: %s\n", string);
 json_object * jobj = json_tokener_parse(string);
 json_parse(jobj);
}
```

The error I am getting is:
ex.c: In function âjson_parseâ:
ex.c:21:2: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
ex.c: At top level:
ex.c:27:27: error: parameter 1 (âvalâ) has incomplete type

I am new to JSON can anybody tell me where I am going wrong. It is somehow to do with the way I am accessing the JSON string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know that json lib very well, but to call json_parse right after calling json_tokener_parse looks... wrong.

Comment: Can you clean up the formatting of your code, and highlight the line of code that is causing the issue? It would be easier to help you that way.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely C standpoint, it seems that the definition of the `json_object` type is not visible to your program.  You might have to restrict yourself to pointers to these objects, *i.e.*, `json_object  *`.  Be sure to correctly allocate and deallocate the pointed-to objects; your JSON library (which are you using?) should have examples & documentation.

Since you’re new to JSON, try writing a simple program that can correctly parse and print a JSON object; the examples on [Wikipedia’s JSON entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) should do nicely for test objects.  Once you’re comfortable with that (shouldn’t take too long) you should find it fairly straight forward to store the emitted strings anywhere you like.